# DataView.RowFilter to find Like '%*%'

Tags: vb.net

The RowFilter does not seem to filter on the * char. 
IE
    `DefaultView.RowFilter = "[Street1] like '%*%'"`
is there any other string I could use in the RowFilter that would find the * char in provided column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8):

> Both the * and % can be used interchangeably for wildcard characters
>   in a LIKE comparison. If the string in a LIKE clause contains a * or
>   %, those characters should be enclosed in brackets ([]).

So the solution is

```
DefaultView.RowFilter = "[Street1] like '%[*]%'"
```